# TensorFlow sparse_softmax_cross_entropy rank error

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to build an RNN with LSTM on TensorFlow. Both the input and output are 5000 by 2 matrices, where the columns represent the features. Those matrices are then fed to the batchX and batchY placeholders which enable the backpropagation. The main definition of the code is at the bottom. I am getting the following error :

> "Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 2) should equal rank of logits minus 1 (received 2)."

I have checked both `logits_series` and `labels_series` and they seem to both contain backpropagation amount of tensors of the shape of `[batch_size, num_features]`

The thing I am confused about is the following: since logits are predictions of labels, shouldn't they have the same dimensions?

```py
'''
RNN definitions

input_dimensions = [batch_size, truncated_backprop_length, num_features_input] 
output_dimensions = [batch_size, truncated_backprop_length, num_features_output]
state_dimensions = [batch_size, state_size]
'''
batchX_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (batch_size, truncated_backprop_length, num_features_input))
batchY_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (batch_size, truncated_backprop_length, num_features_output))
init_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (batch_size, state_size))
inputs_series = tf.unstack(batchX_placeholder, axis=1)
labels_series = tf.unstack(batchY_placeholder, axis=1)

w = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(num_features_input+state_size,state_size), dtype = tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(np.zeros((batch_size, state_size)), dtype = tf.float32)
w2 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(state_size, num_features_output), dtype = tf.float32)
b2 = tf.Variable(np.zeros((batch_size, num_features_output)), dtype=tf.float32)

#calculate state and output variables

state_series = []
output_series = []
current_state = init_state
#iterate over each truncated_backprop_length
for current_input in inputs_series:
    current_input = tf.reshape(current_input,[batch_size, num_features_input])
    input_and_state_concatenated = tf.concat([current_input,current_state], 1)
    next_state = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(input_and_state_concatenated, w) + b)
    state_series.append(next_state)
    current_state = next_state
    output = tf.matmul(current_state, w2)+b2
    output_series.append(output)

#calculate expected output for each state    
logits_series = [tf.matmul(state, w2) + b2 for state in state_series] 
#print(logits_series)
predictions_series = [tf.nn.softmax(logits) for logits in logits_series]
'''
batchY_placeholder = np.zeros((batch_size,truncated_backprop_length))
for i in range(batch_size):
    for j in range(truncated_backprop_length):
        batchY_placeholder[i,j] = batchY1_placeholder[j, i, 0]+batchY1_placeholder[j, i, 1]
'''
print("logits_series", logits_series)
print("labels_series", labels_series)
#calculate losses given each actual and calculated output
losses = [tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits, labels = labels) for logits, labels in zip(logits_series,labels_series)]
total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses)
```

Comment: Is the last dimension of your label (w/ 2 elements) in one-hot format? If you use `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, that dimension should be reduced (i.e. [5000]), each element stores the corresponding class label (e.g. 0 or 1).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And yes, you are absolutely correct that the last dimension of the label is in one-hot format. Should I reduce it by converting two one-hot dimensions into a single dimension with elements 0,1,2,3?

Comment: Condense the classes as you said and reduce the last dimension.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Maosi Chen, I found the issue. It was because the

> tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Requires labels to have one less dimension than logits. Specifically, the labels argument takes values of the shape `[batch_size] and the dtype int32 or int64`

I solved the issue by enumerating the one hot encoded labels I had, reducing the dimension

However, it was also possible to use

> tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Which does not have the dimension reduction requirement, as it takes labels values with shape `[batch_size, num_classes] and dtype float32 or float64.`